# Why does Android CDD advise against using a temperature sensor other than CPU temperature sensor

Tags: android, android-compatibility, cts

The Android CDD states as follows

---

> 7.3.7. Thermometer Device implementations MAY but SHOULD NOT include a thermometer (i.e. temperature sensor.) If a device implementation does
>   include a thermometer, it MUST measure the temperature of the device
>   CPU. It MUST NOT measure any other temperature. (Note that this sensor
>   type is deprecated in the Android 4.2 APIs.)

---

It says that you can have a temperature sensor only to measure the CPU temperature.
Can anyone please tell me why android does not want environmental temperature sensors?

Answer (score 1):

Android does not require device manufacturers to build any particular types of sensors into their Android-powered devices, so devices can have a wide range of sensor configurations.

Most phones only include cpu temperature measurement sensor Sensor.TYPE_TEMPERATURE (this no longer gives accurate readings) It been replaced with.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE Because of this, there isn't an accurate way to measure temperature of different hardware within most phones; hence the restriction to only CPU temperature which almost all android phones should be able to produce

Comment: Sorry I don't seem to understand your answer. I don't understand the reason that you give for Android CDD to say, devices MUST NOT measure any other temperature other than CPU temperature.